# Is ANOVA just a panel data model with dummy variables for group?

Tags: anova, categorical-data, panel-data

This might be a silly question, but I'm confused why ANOVA is different from a panel data model, with dummy variables for group, and inference on the coefficients on the dummy variables. Is this what ANOVA is? Am I missing something important about ANOVA? Thanks for your help.

Related to [Linear Regression and ANOVA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64286/linear-regression-and-anova)

Realized that this is a duplicate: [Why is ANOVA taught / used as if it is a different research methodology compared to linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555/why-is-anova-taught-used-as-if-it-is-a-different-research-methodology-compared)

Comment: Depends more than a little on how you define panel data models. But's it's correct that simple versions of ANOVA can be recast as regression with indicator (you say dummy) variables. You would have a hard time translating all the extra apparatus surrounding ANOVA into regression terms; opinions vary on how much would be missed.

Comment: Can you provide an example of something that would be missing / difficult to recast in a regression?

Comment: Look at the later chapters of any text emphasising ANOVA and especially what you do afterwards. (In my previous comment "But's" is a bad typo.)